# get_map error in R

Tags: r, ggmap

After a lenghty coordinate transformation, available [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/277030/converting-projected-coordinates-from-bbox-into-long-lat-using-r) I want to display the area - more specifically i want to display the aerial image so i can later on use it to plot my data on.

```
> ggmap(map)
> tschamut <- ggmap(map)+
+       scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-13.4003, -13.39943), expand = c(0, 0)) +
+       scale_y_continuous(limits = c(35.419, 35.41961), expand = c(0, 0))
Scale for 'x' is already present. Adding another scale for 'x', which will
replace the existing scale.
Scale for 'y' is already present. Adding another scale for 'y', which will
replace the existing scale.
> tschamut
Error in grid.Call.graphics(C_raster, x$raster, x$x, x$y, x$width, x$height,  : 
  cannot allocate memory block of size 16777216 Tb
In addition: Warning message:
Removed 1 rows containing missing values (geom_rect).
```

16777216 Tb is awfull lot, so i guess i must be doing something totally wrong. What is the problem with my code?

What is the argument `expand` for ? I looked up the `get_map` in the Help pages, but there is nothing with regard to this argument.

Comment: `cannot allocate memory block of size 16777216 Tb` You have terabytes of data there... Do you have a reproducible example?

Comment: how is `map` defined?

Comment: reproducible example here and how I defined the mop here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/277030/converting-projected-coordinates-from-bbox-into-long-lat-using-r

Answer (score 0):

You mixed up your x (lon) and y (lat) coordinates.

#### Correct code

```
tschamut <- ggmap(map) +
    scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-13.4003, -13.39943), expand = c(0, 0)) +
    scale_x_continuous(limits = c(35.419, 35.41961), expand = c(0, 0))
```

#### Data

(from [your question on GIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/277030/converting-projected-coordinates-from-bbox-into-long-lat-using-r))

```
library(ggmap)
library(ggplot2)

# Set a range
lat <- c(-13.40025, -13.3986)                
lon <- c(35.41811, 35.42041)   

# Get a map
map <- get_map(location = c(lon = mean(lon), lat = mean(lat)), zoom = 14,
               maptype = "satellite", source = "google")
```